# Converting a raw print data stream containing PCL commands to PDF

Tags: centos, networking, text-processing, conversion

I have a program that sends raw print data through samba to typically PCL compatible printers. The program is written so basic PCL commands control how it prints.

When sending it to the printer it prints out correctly. However, I know need to be able to take this stream and convert it to a pdf file. I know this can be done but have not been able to find a good explanation as to how to do it.

I know that it would require a CUPS filter but am totally lost on how to modify it to take the raw stream sent to a queue, reroute it to pcl2pdf, then save it to a file.

Any guidance much appreciate. I have only basic sysadmin knowledge as this particular program is written in mvbasic ran by a Rocket D3 system on CentOS 6.6

Comment: starting points seem to be http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.printing.cups.general/18295 and https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Printing_to_PDF

Answer (score 1):

To convert PCL to PDF, you can use GhostPCL (part of GhostPDL project). Command line example is copied below from [here](http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/ghostpcl.html) .

> pcl6 -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=c:\test.pdf c:\test.pcl

It seems that GhostPCL shares code but is different from Ghostscript. He/she has shared binaries for some OS but likely not for CentOS 6.6. You can download the package and compile your own binary from here  [google code archive](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ghostscript/downloads) - search for GhostPDL